# Track keyboard position in iOS 5 with undocked / splited keyboard

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uikit

I have a view that's supposed to be exactly on top of the keyboard, but i'm not using an UITextView, so i can't use inputAccesoryView.

Anyway, prior to iOS 5 i had no problems, the issue comes with an undocked / split keyboard. Now, i have to listen to changes in the keyboard frame with UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification, so i do

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                           selector:@selector(keyFrameChanged:) 
                               name:UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification
                                   object:self.view.window];
```

So once the keyboard is moved, the following gets called

```
- (void) keyFrameChanged:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSDictionary* userInfo = [notification userInfo];  
    CGRect keyboardEndFrame;
    [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] getValue:&keyboardEndFrame];

    // Animate view with keyboardEndFrame data
}
```

The problem is, 99% of the time, UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey returns null, so i don't have a clue about the keyboard's position.

Thanks!

**PS:** I managed to attach the view as an inputAccesoryView, by overriding this property in my UIResponder's subclass (is not readonly anymore), but i still want to know how to track the keyboard's frame.

Comment: Have you tried registering for `UIKeyboard`**Did**`ChangeFrameNotification` instead? The end frame information might just not be passed along in the preview notification.